# Selecting the index that satisfies a condition in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have updated the problem statement to help solve the problem of identifying the coordinate pair list that has the shortest distance to a specific coordinate pair. I have a variable length 2D list / array like the following
:

```
 d = [[[10,10],[20,20]],[[40,40],[60,60],[20,20]],[[60,60],[20,20],[30,30],[10,10]],[[70,70],[20,20]]]
```

I want a list of the indexes of element within the list which is closest to [80, 80].

The answer should be: 
`[1, 1, 0, 0]`

What is the best pythonic way to do it? @tom-fuller and @Skycc mentioned a great way to do this, but I need to go further by one more and look at a pair of values to satisfy the condition. Based on what was recommended, I tried;

```
[i.index(min(i, key=lambda x:np.linalg.norm(x-[80,80]))) for i in d]
```

This did not work. I suspect that the min function with the iterable i here is causing me grief.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lambda` to take away 8 from all the values in the list, then get the value which is closest to 0 using `min`

> **Single integers**

```
d=[[1,2],[4,6,2],[6,2,3,1],[7,2]]
closest = []

for x in d:
    closest.append(x.index(min(x, key = lambda y:abs(y-8))))

print(closest)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension

```
d = [[1,2],[4,6,2],[6,2,3,1],[7,2]]
close8 = [i.index(min(i, key=lambda x:abs(x-8))) for i in d]
# [1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks and thanks to  @tom-fuller as well. Getting greedier;  consider the input list 'd' as the following. Sorry about formatting if incorrect.

` d = [[[10,10],[20,20]],[[40,40],[60,60],[20,20]],[[60,60],[20,20],[30,30],[10,10]],[[70,70],[20,20]]]`

In the above, each innermost list is a coordinate pair and I want to find the list of indexes of minimum distance from the point to a fixed point [80,80]. So, I thought I can try your solution to this and I wrote the following;

' [i.index(min(i, key=lambda x:numpy.linalg.norm(x-[80,80]))) for i in d]'

This did not work, not sure why.

Comment: The error is here `x-[80,80]`, you cannot use - when working with lists. There is a formula to work out the exact distance between two points, is this what you want?

Comment: Tom, I want to find the index of the coordinate pair that has shortest distance, given that the input is a multi length multi dimensional data structure. The answer should still be [1, 1, 0, 0]

Comment: Great! `[1, 1, 0, 0]` is the output given by my other answer, the for loop is the same length as before, I've just split it up to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

Here's an almost vectorized approach -

```
def closestID(a, value):
    a = np.concatenate(d)
    lens = np.array(list(map(len,d)))
    r = np.abs(a-value)
    ids = np.arange(len(lens)).repeat(lens)
    b = np.column_stack((r,ids))
    startidx = np.append(0,lens[:-1].cumsum())
    out = np.lexsort(b.T)[startidx] - startidx
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [92]: d
Out[92]: [[8, 1, 2, 7], [4, 6, 2, 8], [6, 2, 3, 8, 1], [7, 2, 10], [5, 7, 2, 6, 4]]

In [93]: closestID(d,8)
Out[93]: array([0, 3, 3, 0, 1])

In [94]: closestID(d,6)
Out[94]: array([3, 1, 0, 0, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

The distance between two points can be found using pythagarous, `a2 + b2 = c2`. Using this logic you want to find the smallest value of `c2`, this can be done the same way as before, the code is all one line I've just split it up to make it easier to see.

> **Co-ordinates**

```
d = [[[10,10],[20,20]],[[40,40],[60,60],[20,20]],[[60,60],[20,20],[30,30],[10,10]],[[70,70],[20,20]]]
point = [80, 80]
closest = []

for List in d:
    close = List.index(                     # position
        min(List,                           # smallest
            key = lambda p:                 # lambda for each coordinate in the list
                (point[0] - p[0]) ** 2 +    # a2 
                (point[1] - p[1]) ** 2      # b2
    ))    
    closest.append(close)                   # add it to the list

print(closest)
```

> **In your context:**

So you have a list like this `[image, image, image]`

Each image contains objects `[[object], [object, object], [object, object]]`

Each object has two points `[[[point, point]], [[point, point], [point, point]]]...`

And each point has an x and y coordinate e.g. `[10, 10]`

Your code should look like this:

```
d = ...
closest = []

for image in d:
    point = # MIDPOINT of image

    for object in image:
        # this is the same as the code above just with List switched for object
        close = object.index(min(object, key = lambda p: (point[0] - p[0]) ** 2 + (point[1] - p[1]) ** 2))    
        closest.append(close)

print(closest)
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. This works. I was losing the plot trying to use the numpy distance calculator function.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)

Comment: Tom, my program's list that serves as input for your suggested comprehension has one more dimension, like below;
`d=[[[[53, 54]]], 
   [[[51, 51]]], 
   [[[39, 39]], [[53, 54]]], 
   [[[39, 39]], [[54, 54]]], 
   [[[54, 53]]], 
   [[[52, 52]]]
  ]`
When I apply your solution, unsurprisingly, it does not work correctly presumably because I have introduced a new dim. Clearly my understanding of python lists leaves a lot to be desired. Any thoughts?

Comment: What does your program do? So lets say you have points a, b and c. Lets say a = `[53,54]`, b = `[51,51]`, and c = `[39,39]`. This means your list d will look like this: `d = [   [[a]], [[b]], [[c], [a]]...` This doesn't make sense to me, in your question d is a list of lists of points, in that comment d seems to me like random brackets everywhere. What is your list d used for in your program?

Comment: The points are actually a pair for a bounding box [[rowmin, col min], [rowmax, colmax]] for each object in an image. for an image, there are several objects in an image and there are several images in one set. 

I can DM you the code segment if needed.

Comment: In that case, your first dimension would be image, `[image, image, image]`, next you want objects, `[[object], [object, object], [object, object]]`, finally for each object you want a minimum and maximum point. Your code should look like this: `for image in d: #Next Line# for object in image:` then `object[0]` is the minimum and `object[1]` is the maximum.

Comment: An Image can have many objects and each object will have two pairs of coordinates which are the NW and SE corner of the bounding boxes [[NW],[SE]]. For my distance calculation, I only pick object[0] as that is enough to calc the distance from a fixed point [92,92], mid point of my image

Comment: Sounds interesting! I can add another answer if that helps, also should the program calculate the midpoint of each image, or is it saved as a variable?

Comment: Tom, sorry, I just saw this. It will be good to have the mid point as well.